What causes Cmd+W and similar shortcuts stop working in Edge randomly?
On my MacBook Pro 16, Cmd+W and like shortcuts (Cmd+C sometimes) stop working in edge randomly. I have to restart Edge to fix or use Cmd+W in Finder to make it work again in Edge.
What could be the reason? I don't see this behavior when using Edge in Windows or Ubuntu.
